# springboot project java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to build .jar file from my springboot project, but I keep getting this error.
I've been getting this same error for two days and cannot solve it although I did a lot of googling.. help needed!! :(

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Cannot load driver class: ${DB_DRIVER}

Below is my application.yml, I added environmental variables in my IntelliJ.

```
spring:
  database: mysql
  datasource:
    url: ${DB_URL}
    driver-class-name: ${DB_DRIVER}
    username: ${DB_USER}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    # 개발 초기 단계는 create 또는 update
    # 테스트 서버는 update 또는 validate
    # 스테이징과 운영 서버는 validate 또는 none

    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate.format_sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Also, this is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.cookiee'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:2.2.6.RELEASE'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1'


    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    // 구글 로그인을 위해 구글에서 제공하는 simple-json 라이브러리 사용
    implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I tried editing application.yml and build.gradle, but none of them worked. I also tried adding mysql-connector-j.jar to the classpath, but it didn't work.

Comment: It seems, env variable `${DB_DRIVER}` is not replaced. Can you try replacing it with the actual value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect Java to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database)

Comment: It looks like either 
1> Your app is not reading the env var correctly. Can you print it out somewhere to confirm the value?
2> It's possible you need to download the driver / make sure it is installed